# PSU compability

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, case

I would like to ask a few questions about this PSU:
RM Series™ RM1000 — 1000 Watt 80 PLUS® Gold Certified Fully Modular PSU

```
Computer specifications:

Case: Compucase 6C11BS-UT
Motherboard: MB H77 S1155 MATX GA-Z77-DS3H
CPU: i7-3770 3.4 GHz 8M LGA1155
Hard drive: Samsung 500GB ST500DM005 SATA
Graphics card: **TWO** GIGABYTE GV-N970G1 GAMING-4GD GeForce GTX 970 4GB


Case specs:

Height:41 cm
Width:19 cm
Max Mainboard Size:ATX
Front Accessible Bays Qty:6
Cooling System:Rear : 120 mm fan x 1
```

Will it fit in my case? Will it run with two Nvdia GTX GIGABYTE GV-N970G1 GAMING-4GD GeForce GTX 970 4GB? Is it better than EVGA SuperNOVA 1000G2?

Answer (score 0):

EVGA SuperNOVA 1000G2 port:

- 6 port: SATA+periphery
- 6 port: 6+2 PCI-E
- 2 port: **4+4 CPU**

RM Series™ RM1000 port:

- 6 port: SATA+periphery
- 6 port: 6+2 PCI-E **& 4+4 CPU**
- 1 port: C-LINK(Corsair Link port) connect to USB 2.0 port

  Corsairs Link Dashboard:

[image: Corsairs Link Dashboard]

Video:

[Corsair RM1000 Power Supply - RM Series 1000W [Unboxing + First Look]](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qsDlw_7ygk)

[EVGA SuperNOVA 1000 G2 Power Supply Overview](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWNQUpe0TCI)

Comment: I wish that I would understand what do those ports mean but I don't. Is there a straight answer for which is better or do you mean that those PSUs are very similar? Also, is the RM1000 compatible with my system?

Comment: When I read your answer, I thought someone was trolling the site with a nonsense answer.  Then I saw your rep, so I'll assume this was meant as a serious answer.  You name the two PSUs mentioned in the question but otherwise, there is not an obvious relationship between your answer and what was asked.  Can you expand your answer to clearly and directly address what was asked in the question?